# How do you convert C String to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, string

I have been able to find methods like `-[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]` but they do not seem to play well when the cstring is a pointer.

Comment: They work perfectly fine with pointers, you need to be more descriptive about the issues your facing.

Comment: Moreover, *all* C strings are pointers. That's the definition of a C string: a pointer to some characters.

Comment: Actually I think you are talking about converting CString to NSString :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First up, don't use `initWithCString`, it has been deprecated.

Couple of ways you can do this:

```
const *char cString = "Hello";
NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString];
```

If you need another encoding like ASCII:

```
const *char cString = "Hello";
NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If you want to see all the string encodings available, in Xcode, hold **command + option** then **double click** on `NSASCIIStringEncoding` in the above code block.

You will be able to see where Apple have declared their enumeration for the string encoding types. Bit quicker than trying to find it in the documentation.

Some other ones you might need:

```
NSASCIIStringEncoding
NSUnicodeStringEncoding // same as NSUTF16StringEncoding
NSUTF32StringEncoding
```

Checkout Apple's [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) (encodings are at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 38):

With modern Objective-C (since Xcode 5 at least) you can just do:

```
char const* cString = "Hello";
NSString *myNSString = @(cString);
```

Comment: Thats short and sweet. plus one for that :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you do a "convert to modern objective-c syntax" in xcode, it converts to this format.

Answer (score 12):

`stringWithCString:encoding:` creates an NSString from a given C string. To create a C string from an NSString, use either the `UTF8String` method (generally preferred) or `cStringUsingEncoding:` (if you need an encoding other than UTF-8).

Comment: Since the cString method is deprecated, this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: yeah my bad, i've fixed this now