# Not able resolve a NULL cString crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Hi I have following code which crashes the app:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithCString:[[[self.arrayForTableSelLang objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kSupport_question_title] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The error is:

`* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString`

NSLog gives me:

`Wie lange dauert es, bis meine Guthaben-Ãœberweisung auf meiner Karte gebucht ist?`

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895152/memory-management-nsstrings-stringwithcstringencoding

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509728/how-do-you-convert-cstring-to-nsstring

Comment: As I see, message is pretty clear. Try to divide that line of code into few, so you could see the reason. Good luck.

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko Would you tell me how to divide the code? or whats wrong in my code?

Comment: @user1954352, I don't know, what's wrong in your code. Because the problem is outside provided line. And it's not regarding ios of obj-c. It's about logic.

Comment: And you are messing the encoding of the string. You can't export in ISO Latin 1 and then import UTF-8 back, because that would result in messed letters.

Answer (score 0):

I meant this:

```
NSDictionary *langDict = self.arrayForTableSelLang[indexPath.row];
NSString *string = langDict[kSupport_question_title];
char *cString = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**UPDATE**

Update the code this way:

```
NSDictionary *langDict = self.arrayForTableSelLang[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = langDict[kSupport_question_title];
```

Comment: I got the same result after implementing above code.

Comment: That's right. But now you can debug the code and see at what line nil is returned.

Comment: I did that task and in my question I also mentioned that when I got "Wie lange dauert es, bis meine Guthaben-Ãœberweisung auf meiner Karte gebucht ist?" it returns nil.

Comment: And how could anybody on stackoverflow know what's the reason of printing that line in your logs?

Comment: @user1954352, When you said that NSLog gave you something, did you mean that it's input c-string for stringWithCString: method?

Comment: My input string is:"Wie lange dauert es, bis meine Guthaben-\U00c3\U0153berweisung auf meiner Karte gebucht ist?";

Comment: @user1954352, Why do you convert NSString to c-string and then back to NSString? You can use result of langDict[kSupport_question_title] operation as text for the label.

Comment: @holex there’s no need for name-calling. Everyone was a beginner once.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, you are right, but I saw that the OP was not even able to split his own code(?) into 4-5 different lines... that indicated me, probably the OP has zero clue what the referred line does or what it even means.

Comment: @user1954352, did my suggestion fix your problem?